# Can I use flutter without having git in my PATH?

Tags: git, flutter, path

Can I use flutter without having git in my PATH environment variables? 
I already have git installed but I don't want to add it in the environment variables. As far as I know, flutter requires git to be in PATH; Is there any workaround?
I'm looking to give my git.exe location to flutter, so it could use it from there. I don't know how to proceed.

Sorry, if I'm asking the wrong questions, just trying to learn.

Comment: shortly, yes, you just need to specify the path to the flutter shell script and to the folder of your project.

Comment: I know you specifically said you don't want to add git to the environment variables, but can I ask why not?

Comment: @Vitor could you elaborate a little on the procedure. your method sounds plausible.

Comment: @adamgy I doubt I can make a convincing argument, but let's just say I like it that way :D

Comment: I think what @Vitor is referring to is that you would have modify the script(s) where flutter uses the git command, changing 'git' to '<your_path>/git.exe'. This could probably be done with a script; alternatively, maybe you could use an [alias](https://shapeshed.com/unix-alias/) or [doskey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-aliases) to set the 'git' command to reference your git executable.

Comment: @adamgy I don't have the faintest clue as to where I should modify the flutter script. I understand I need to change the location where flutter looks for it. Could you say how?

Comment: @SmarthBansal in Linux you can use grep, in Windows you can use something like [findstr](https://www.itechtics.com/using-findstr-windows/) to find all occurrences of a string

Comment: @SmarthBansal Also, can you provide info on where and how you get an error related to git?

Comment: Hey, @SmarthBansal looking for the same thing did you find any solution for it ??

Comment: @AtulChaudhary No did not. ended up adding it to the path.